# Is it possible to get video's source of claim

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i i'm developing an app to retrieve data of my channel, i'm using contentDetails.licensedContent  boolean to check if a video is claimed or not,but can i get the source of claim, reason for this video to get claimed and who is reporting it? Many thanks.

Claim reason: string
Source: string

Comment: On what URL or how are you able to retrieve these informations from the YouTube UI?

Comment: Claims such as copyright are checked at player load and that data is not available through the API for whatever reason.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.